# Documentation change history should be filterable

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, documentation, filtering, proposed-changes

Why there are no filter in changes history here:  https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/history

I think it will be good to add an option to filter by **user**, by **tag**, or by **outcome** (Reject/Approve).

Comment: User: `http://stackoverflow.com/users/<id>/?tab=documentation&sort=proposedchanges`; tag: `http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/<tag>?tab=proposedchanges`.

Comment: this is not helpfull @JF

Comment: Why isn’t it helpful?

Comment: Generaly change in the link is not an helpful way, i'm wrong

Comment: The main site doesn't have such filters on the revision history either...

Comment: @braiam maybe it should.

Comment: Nothing is perfect so we are a community here, so we try to make this place better more tha's all @Braiam

Comment: Well, I don't think that filters would make easier to answer the *who-did-what-and-when* questions.

Comment: Interesting idea and one we did consider. For future reference, it's helpful to explain the use case you have in mind when proposing a feature. I imagined a few possible abuse scenarios and it was not obvious what you hoped to accomplish. (I don't think you intended to, say, harass people who accepted too many changes but others might.)